# Identifying "Other User" on Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, laptop, remote-desktop, windows-networking

At work there is a laptop that is shared by more than one person.
The laptop is connected to the internal network.

When nobody is using the laptop, I can successfully use Remote Desktop Connection and sign in to the laptop.

When I use Remote Desktop, and somebody is "signed on" (Windows 10 lingo), I get a message window stating that another User is logged on.  No mention of the account name.

I would like to "ping" or contact the person who is logged onto the laptop.

How do I find out who is presently signed onto the Windows 10 laptop, that is connected to our network?

*Note:  The laptop is located in a lab.  Due to COVID19 many of the Users are working remotely and may not be in the lab.  Other cases, the person forgot to "sign out"*

*Note:  I'm on a Windows7 Desktop PC using Remote Desktop Connection to a laptop running Windows 10.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qwinsta command will be helpful if you would like to query session or username remotely.

Example when I queried info from local PC to the remote one.
[image]

MS reference link:

**How to use qwinsta**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/qwinsta